# How to change border or userControl z-order in runtime in WPF ??

Tags: wpf

I dont find any way to do it

Someone can help me here ?

Comment: How are these two questions related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a controls in a Panel you can use the [Panel.SetZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.setzindex.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change Z order your elements need to be contained in a common Panel which supports layering of elements, most commonly a Grid or Canvas. The Panel.ZIndex attached property is used to set the relative Z order of your elements.